# Using jQuery to Independently Toggle a Nested List of Checkboxes

Tags: jquery-selectors, toggle, checkbox, children, nested-lists

```
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-1" />Item 1
    <ul class="sublist">
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-1-sublist" />Item 1-1</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-1-sublist" />Item 1-2</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-1-sublist" />Item 1-3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input type="checkbox" name="item-2" />Item 2
     <ul class="sublist">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-2-sublist" />Item 2-1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-2-sublist" />Item 2-2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-2-sublist" />Item 2-3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Considering the code above, if the user clicks on one of the main-level checkboxes (ie, Item 1 or Item 2), how would I go about toggling all checkboxes in the neighboring list with the `sublist` class value? I don't want to use any other class or id values because I'll have several types of sublists that need to be toggled independently; I don't want to duplicate chunks of code for each set of class/id values.

I've had the toggle-all-children-of neighbor but I've had to scrap that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [$.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) functions, like so ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eDJnP/7/)):

```
$('input[name="item-1"], input[name="item-2"]').change(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this), checked = checkbox.is(':checked');
  $('ul.sublist input[type="checkbox"]', checkbox.parent()).attr('checked', checked);
})
```

This code could be a little cleaner if your child check boxes had a name that didn't start with the same string as their parents like so:

```
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="item-1" />Item 1
    <ul class="sublist">
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="sublist-item-1-1" />Item 1-1</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="sublist-item-1-2" />Item 1-2</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="sublist-item-1-3" />Item 1-3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input type="checkbox" name="item-2" />Item 2
     <ul class="sublist">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="sublist-item-2-1" />Item 2-1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="sublist-item-2-2" />Item 2-2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="sublist-item-2-3" />Item 2-3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
$('input[name^="item-"]').change(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this), checked = checkbox.is(':checked');
  $('ul.sublist input[type="checkbox"]', checkbox.parent()).attr('checked', checked);
})
```

This uses the pseudo selector `^=` which means starts with.  You could use that in your original HTML because your child selectors all start with the name string.

**------Edit------**

For a better result use **prop** instead of **attr**, sometimes the **attr** [works only the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17060460/5656276) you change the values. So it would be:

```
$('input[name^="item-"]').change(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this), checked = checkbox.is(':checked');
  $('ul.sublist input[type="checkbox"]', checkbox.parent()).prop('checked', checked);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just used those checkobox `name` values arbitrarily, so my code started out with `$('input**[type="checkbox"]**').change(function()'

Comment: @davidChapela, good edit, the technicals difference between the two approaches is that  `attr` returns the literal value defined in the HTML while `prop` returns the interpreted value from the DOM, in this case `prop` is better