# Check all check box does not works the second time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

The check all check box  first time checks and unchecks well but not at the second time. The code is as follows

**HTML**

```
<th align="left" width="25" style="color:#FFF; background-color:#3A4048">
    <%= check_box_tag "select_all" %>
</th>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#select_all").click(function () {
    $('td input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Can any body help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#select_all").click(function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.prop()` is preferred to `.attr()` for the checked property. Also the `.change()` event would be more appropriate for a checkbox.

```
$("#select_all").change(function () {
    $('td input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: @Jeff if this solved it, consider accepting the answer (you can only accept one answer so be sure to choose the most helpful answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).prop('checked')` Latest `jQuery Code`.

```
$("#select_all").click(function () {
    $('td input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#select_all").bind('click',function () {
    $('td input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```